# Classes used as a datatype for datatemplates must have parameterless constructors

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatemplate

So I have a class which I need to specify in a datatemplate, as so

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type m:AbortAction}">
```

I need to do this, because I am binding an items control to a collection of "BaseActions", which is an abstract class and I need to display each differently depending on their class.

if, in AbortAction I do not provide a constructor taking 0 arguments, then the above line of XAML becomes invalid. However, I never want someone to instantiate in code an AbortAction without providing a parameter (I have another constructor for this).

It feels inelegant to have both constructors, and assume no user will ever use the constructor without parameters. (I currently throw an exception there, but its still inelegant).

Is there an elegant solution?

Comment: You don't instantiate your class there... so why care about the constructor ?

Comment: I dont instantiate the class, where? in the XAML? Because if you remove the constructor without the parameter but have a constructor that takes a parameter instead, then it isn't valid to reference it in the XAML as I posted above. It requires a parameterless constructor else it will not compile.

Comment: I guess you are not telling the whole story here... Something else throwing that exception, perhaps you can show rest of the Template ?  DataType={x:Type m:AbortActions} is equivalent to var type = typeof(AbortAction) it will just return the type regardless of how many constructors or which type of constructors

Comment: No. If I autocomplete just after the m:, The AbortActions only appears in that list if it has a parameterless constructor available. It can be seen with an empty DataTemplate. Just have a class which has a constructor taking an int but no ctor taking 0 parameters... and Autocomplete using an empty data template will not show that class as available at all.

Comment: Ok, but there is a difference between AutoComplete not showing it and your project not compiling. Did you try it anyway and compile ? It should work regardless of how the constructor looks.